# If Firebase is added via Android Studio to project, does it automatically extend to the whole ionic project?

Tags: android, cordova, firebase-cloud-messaging, ionic4, firebase-analytics

I have project that is build in ionic. Android was added with cordova.
If I add Firebase Analytics and Push Notification (Cloud Messaging) via the android studio wizard. Will it apply to the whole project or not?

We are using ionic 4, and i tried doing it with cordova libraries but got a lot of errors, unmet dependencies and obsoletes.

*UPDATE*

As user rtpHarry said I am trying to do it with ionic and cordova. I am fallowing this guide https://pointdeveloper.com/firebase-analytics-for-ionic-apps-logging-custom-events/.
This time I had no problem with adding plugins.

But as soon as I added a provider with //ionic g provider eventLogger (and the code from the guide) i get white screen after splash screen
when running the app with ionic //cordova run android --device

*UPDATE 2*
Solved above problem by adding EventLoggerProvider and FirebaseAnalytics to the providers section in app.module.ts

Answer (score 0):

You are supposed to use the web version, not the android or ios version with Ionic.

You should try to do it the proper way, and then share the detailed error messages on here.

There are some common errors that happen doing it this way but without knowing more we can't really help.

One of them is where different plugins try to include different versions of Google Services causing lots of build errors. You have to fix it doing something like this:

```
dependencies {

classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'

classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:+' // <-- here

}
```

but like I said, please post your proper errors for more clear answers.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! 
I'll see with my project manager if they need firebase on the web or not. If yes, I'll try. 
But the last time I tried I resolved at lest 20 if not more errors and every time there was a new one. So I don't look forward to it. 
In the mean time do you have an up to date guide/tutorial witch you recommend?

Comment: If you are using Ionic then you are on the web. It might compile into a native application but its all run through the webview so it's classed as web. That is what Hybrid Apps are, even if you are deploying it to Android / ios.

Comment: Yeah, i know it's all run through the webview. I'll try doing it with ionic and cordova. I'll post it here if I have any problems I can't resolve.
Thanks again.